# Java FXML Get controller instance from another controller

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, controller, javafx-2

I am attempting to get my customer's name in my MenuController class. The customer is created in my CustomerController class. However, I keep getting a NullPointer Exception Error. Is there something I am doing wrong.?

This is the MenuController class method that is involved

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MenuController.class.getResource("Order.fxml"));

        FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Customer.fxml"));
        try {
            Parent root = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomerController dac = (CustomerController) loader2.getController();

        cust = dac.customer;
        System.out.println(cust.getFirstName());
```

Here is the Customer Controller method

```
 continueBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(CustomerController.class.getResource("Menu.fxml"));


        try {
            view = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            customer = new Customer(firstNameTextField.getText(), lastNameTextField.getText());
            closeCurrentWindow(continueBtn);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Customer is not created until the continueBtn action is fired.  That maybe causing your issue based on what I see.  You may have to provide more code otherwise.